# FInd duplicate rows and show only the earliest

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

```
respid, uploadtime
```

I need a query that will show all the records that respid is duplicate and show them except the latest (by upload time)
exmple:

```
4   2014-01-01
4   2014-06-01 
4   2015-01-01
4   2015-06-01
4   2016-01-01
```

In this case the query should return four records (the latest is : 4    2016-01-01 )

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT respid, uploadtime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY respid ORDER BY uploadtime DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT respid, uploadtime
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1
ORDER BY respid, uploadtime;
```

The logic here is to show all records except those having the first row number value, which would be the latest records for each `respid` group.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted your question correctly, then you want to see all records where `respid` occurs multiple times, but exclude the last duplicate.

Translating this to SQL could sound like *"show all records that have a later record for the same `respid`"*. That is exactly what the solution below does. It says that for every row in the result a later record with the same `respid` must exists.

**Sample data**

```
declare @MyTable table
(
    respid int,
    uploadtime date
);

insert into @MyTable (respid, uploadtime) values
(4, '2014-01-01'),
(4, '2014-06-01'),
(4, '2015-01-01'),
(4, '2015-06-01'),
(4, '2016-01-01'),  --> last duplicate of respid=4, not part of result
(5, '2020-01-01');  --> has no duplicate, not part of result
```

**Solution**

```
select mt.respid, mt.uploadtime
from @MyTable mt
where exists (  select top 1 'x'
                from @MyTable mt2
                where mt2.respid = mt.respid
                  and mt2.uploadtime > mt.uploadtime );
```

**Result**

```
respid      uploadtime
----------- ----------
4           2014-01-01
4           2014-06-01
4           2015-01-01
4           2015-06-01
```